# Upper bound condition number

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite, singular-values, condition-number

Let $A$ be a real matrix with all eigenvalues in the interval $(0,1)$. Show that $$\kappa(A)\le\dfrac{2-\lambda_{\min}(A)}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}$$ where $\kappa(A)$ is $A$'s condition number (maximum singular value $\sigma_{\max}(A)$ divided by minimum singular value $\sigma_{\min}(A)$) and $\lambda_{\min}(A)$ is $A$'s smallest eigenvalue. Inspired by [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preconditioner#Linear_preconditioning) if we also assume that $N$ is positive definite.

Let $\lambda_{\max}(A)$ be $A$'s biggest eigenvalue. Then $$\dfrac{\lambda_{\max}(A)}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}<\dfrac{1}{\lambda_{\min(A)}}.$$ $\sigma_{\max}(A)\ge\lambda_{\max}(A)$ and $\sigma_{\min}(A)\le\lambda_{\min}(A)$, so $$\dfrac{\lambda_{\max}(A)}{\lambda_{\min}(A)}\le\kappa(A).$$ If $A$ is normal, equality holds and we're done. I don't know how to proceed if $A$ isn't normal.

Comment: What is $N$? ${}{}$

Comment: It's only in the link. $A=M-N$.

Comment: A problem should be reasonably self contained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} {1 \over 2} & 10,000 \\ 0 & {1 \over 2} \end{bmatrix}$.

The above formula suggests that an upper bound for the condition number is $3$, but 
$\|A^{-1} e_1 \| = 2 $ and $\| Ae_2 \| > 10,000$ so we have $\kappa(A) > 20,000$.

Comment: Thanks. Is the link wrong or does $M^{-1}A$ satisfy something I didn't capture in my reformulation?

Comment: I did not look at the link. I am just pointing out that the formula in the question is not true in general.